# whether a function with a closed interval domain has an antiderivative

Tags: calculus

**Does a function f whose domain is a closed interval have an antiderivative (a function F (whose domain may not be the same as f) that is only differentiable on the domain of f, and the derivative is equal to f on the domain of f)?**

For a function to be the antiderivative (with the definition above) of the above function, its domain must include values outside and near the endpoints of the closed interval in order to differentiable, and it also has to be not differentiable for those values.

Comment: Sorry, what? Why is a constant function not an antiderivative to the $0$ function?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus' proof actually assumes that the domain is a compact interval $[a,b]$, where $F$ will be continuous, and that $F'$ must exist everywhere in the open subinterval $(a,b)$. In the reverse direction, $f$ is assumed continuous on the compact interval $[a,b]$ (otherwise $f$ might not be integrable...)

Comment: @FShrike According to that definition of an antiderivative, they are not because derivatives have different domains.

Comment: @FShrike Does a function whose domain is a closed interval have an antiderivative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be two issues in question: The distinction between open and closed intervals, and differing domains of $f$ and $F$.

If $a < b$ are real, one says a real-valued function $f$ is *differentiable* on $[a, b]$ if $f$ extends to a differentiable function on a larger open interval $(\alpha, \beta) \supset [a, b]$.

If it's of interest, we say $f$ is *continuously-differentiable* if $f$ extends to a continuously-differentiable function on a larger open interval. This is equivalent to saying $f$ is continuous, differentiable in $(a, b)$, and the one-sided limits of the derivative exist at the endpoints.

Particularly, if $f$ is defined on an interval $I$, a function $F$ on $I$ is an *antiderivative* of $f$ if $F$ is differentiable in the preceding sense and $F' = f$ at each point of $I$. For example, if $f$ is identically zero on some interval $I$, then every constant function $F$ on $I$ is an antiderivative of $f$.

Finally, if it matters, "any function whose domain is one or more open interval has an antiderivative" isn't true, but is true if we assume $f$ is continuous (for example).

Comment: So no function whose domain is one closed interval is differentiable on that closed interval because it is not defined for an open interval contains the domain?

Comment: Is it possible for a function to be differentiable at any point in a closed interval which is a subset of its domain, and not differentiable at any point outside that closed interval?

Comment: Just to calibrate regarding the first comment, have you heard the term _extend_, which is used here in a specific mathematical sense? (You've also changed the question, though this answer still addresses the new version: "Yes" a function on a closed bounded interval can have an antiderivative on that interval.)

Comment: I was trying to find if there is any agreed upon definition, but it seems like there is no. I am looking for an antiderivative with my definition (see the bracket in my question). If so, could you give some examples? Is there a general one?

Comment: Not sure I understand what seems to be missing. There _is_ a standard of antiderivative for a real-valued function on a real interval (which may or may not be closed and bounded), given in this answer.

Comment: If a function f is defined on  [a,b] and values outside and near [a,b], then the function is differentiate on [a,b] if an extension of the restriction of the function f (an extension of f|[a,b]) to (c,d) is differentiable?

Comment: I think of it as: If $f$ is defined on $[a, b]$, and if there exists a differentiable extension $\bar{f}$ on $(c, d) \supset [a, b]$, i.e., if $\bar{f}|_{[a,b]} = f$, then by definition $f$ is differentiable on $[a, b]$, and $f'(x) = \bar{f}'(x)$ for all $x$ in $[a, b]$. (This may be exactly what you're saying; just introducing a name for the extension.)

Comment: If [a,b] is a proper subset of the domain of f, does the definition change to “the function is differentiate on [a,b] if an extension of the restriction of the function f (an extension of f|[a,b]) to (c,d) is differentiable”? Is this the general definition of the differentiability of a function on a closed interval, whether the domain of the function is the closed interval or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134467/discussion-between-andrew-d-hwang-and-tfr).